# ALFRESCO ERROR : Mounting point lost of alfresco server now alfresco is not getting up

Tags: mysql, jboss, alfresco

My mounting location has lost

so I created new location and dir.root property pointed to that location

Deleted MYSQL schema and created again

And restarted MYSQL services

But when I am trying to make alfresco up I am getting below error

**Ensure that the 'dir.root' property is pointing to the correct data location.**

**CONTENT INTEGRITY ERROR: System content not found in content store.**

```
2021-08-23 11:16:25,320 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:16:25,320 User:System ERROR [repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] Ensure that the 'dir.root' property is pointing to the correct data location.
2021-08-23 11:16:25,420 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:16:25,364 User:System ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 07230000 Ensure that the 'dir.root' property is pointing to the correct data location.
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.check(ConfigurationChecker.java:312)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.access$000(ConfigurationChecker.java:72)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker$1.execute(ConfigurationChecker.java:178)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:326)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:252)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.onBootstrap(ConfigurationChecker.java:182)
    at org.alfresco.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:77)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:246)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:355)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4348)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5263)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:295)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:108)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy54.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
    at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy55.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "data location" (contentstore) and your database seems to be in a different state. For example, maybe your database is containing some datas which are not present into your "data location".

If you have a backup of your contentstore matching with the state of your DB datas, stop Alfresco, restore it, and start Alfresco.

If you don't have a backup. I have lost your metadatas. Keep your actual contentstore (which) contains binaries of your files. You could search some contents into it and maybe find some.

If you don't care of your datas (because it's a test environment for example), remove your database, recreate it (with the same name for example), empty the contentstore and make a full reindex. Then when you will start Alfresco, it would be good.